# Where to buy a TIM simcard in Malpensa airport?

Tags: cellphones, italy, milan, mxp

I understood it's the best option for travelers' data plan in Italy.

I found a TIM store in Gallarate, but we're landing on Friday at 18:00 and not sure we'll make it on time.

Is there an easier way or something in the airport?

Comment: do they sell TIM simcards?

Comment: keep in mind that you need to provide an ID in order to buy a sim card in Italy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find a TIM point in almost all shopping centers, or phone shops because they are retailers in Italy. You can use the "store search" on the website (You can also shop Sim Card on Online Store) 
https://www.tim.it/trova-negozio?_DARGS=/browse/trovaNegozio.jsp#

The better simcard in Italy are Vodafone, Tim and Wind. I will not recommend '3'.

**UPDATE:**

> Where to buy a TIM simcard in Malpensa airport?

**Terminal 1 on Malpensa:**

- UNIEURO Tel: 0274868157 [here](https://www.unieuro.it/online/negozi/Aeroporto-Malpensa---Terminal-1) 
  All days: 05:00 - 21:00 
  Saturday: 05:00 - 18:00

**Terminal 2 on Malpensa:**

- UNIEURO Tel: 0274868169 [here](https://www.unieuro.it/online/negozi/Aeroporto-Malpensa---Terminal-2) 
  All days: 06:00 - 21:00 
  Saturday: 06:00 - 20:00
- WIND 
  All days: 05:00 - 21:00 
  Saturday: 05:00 - 18:00

**Near Malpensa:**

- Tim Tel: 0331701115 e-mail: gallarate@billsize.it [here](https://www.google.it/maps/place/Tim/@45.6501265,8.7449547,12z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1stim+malpensa!3m4!1s0x0:0x5bcaf0b6ba6a1e3e!8m2!3d45.6597224!4d8.7925279) 
  Piazza della Libertà, 1, 21013 *Gallarate* (VA) (15 minutes car/40 minutes bus)
  Monday 15–19 
  Tuesday/Friday 09:30–13 15:30–19 
  Saturday 09–13 15–19 
  Sunday Close
- Ram S.r.l. (Vodafone) [here](http://trovanegozio.vodafone.it/gallarate/ram-srl/) 
  Piazza San Lorenzo 9, 21013 Gallarate (VA) (15 minutes car)
- 3Store tel: 0331250205 
  Via Pastrengo, 1 Somma Lombardo (VA) - 21019 (15 minutes car)

Check in the [Mobile App](http://www.milanomalpensa-airport.com/en/services/digital-services/mobile-apps) of Milano Malpensa. And If you need something, tell me as well.

Comment: @pnuts edited now.

Comment: I don't saw other guide for Italy :) @pnuts